# vlookup with multiple output and combining filter() with arrayformula()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup, google-sheets-filter

I have 2 sheets : shot and deadline.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1drNUQVtAxd0HU4QCVSKJSsKHoanE735n8HsjkYpYiGs/edit?usp=sharing

This is my **shot** sheet :

[image]

and this is the **deadline** sheet :
[image]

So in the deadline sheet, it's based on the dates. It will pull the shotid from **shot** sheet.

in A2 of deadline sheet , i use :

```
=ifna( filter(shot!$A$2:$A, shot!$B$2:$B=A$1) ,)
```

Then i copy the formula to B2:2. The image2 above is the ideal output i'm looking for. The formula works fine, but i want to make a single arrayformula().

My first trial to use arrayformula() with the previous filter() :

```
=arrayformula( ifna( filter(shot!$A$2:$A, shot!$B$2:$B=A$1:$1) ,))
```

and it returns error. Filter() doesn't work together with arrayformula. So i second trial is using vlookup :

```
=arrayformula( ifna( vlookup( A$1:$1,{ shot!$B$2:$B, shot!$A$2:$A },2,0) ,))
```

it will give me only 1 output per column. The vlookup only find the first match :
[image]

Can anyone help me ? is it possible to use arrayformula() for this case ?

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: Sorry forgot the link, I've included the link in my post. Also here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1drNUQVtAxd0HU4QCVSKJSsKHoanE735n8HsjkYpYiGs/edit?usp=sharing .The expected result is there in the deadline sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `query-pivot-countifs` pattern to get a list of dates in column `B` and the shots in column `A` associated with each date:

```
=arrayformula( 
  transpose(
    query( 
      query( 
        { 
          A1:B, 
          countifs(B1:B, B1:B, row(B1:B), "<=" & row(B1:B)) 
        }, 
        "select Col2, max(Col1) 
         where Col2 is not null 
         group by Col2 
         pivot Col3", 
        1 
      ), 
      "offset 1", 
      0 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Note that the formula will only list dates that actually appear in the data. To get a sparse result, match the output of the formula against your list of dates with an `arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(row())))` pattern, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      A1:1, 
      query( 
        query( 
          { 
            data!A1:B, 
            countifs(data!B1:B, data!B1:B, row(data!B1:B), "<=" & row(data!B1:B)) 
          }, 
          "select Col2, max(Col1) 
           where Col2 is not null 
           group by Col2 
           pivot Col3", 
          1 
        ), 
        "offset 1", 
        0 
      ), 
      row(data!A2:A), 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: sorry can you revisit my post. I've added the link to my sheet. I can't make this script to work

Comment: Thank you for the sample spreadsheet. The formula seems to work fine. To use it in another sheet, prepend `data!` to all range references. Edited the answer to show an example of the `arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(row())))` pattern.

Comment: Fantastic ! sorry, last time i had typo problem.

Comment: Btw, if you have time pls check my other post, to do counta() per row , pls check my link : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/155917/find-counta-per-row-using-arrayformula