# find counta() per row using arrayformula()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have this table :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ICEL33X3ADz7XEH2Cmi1p6mrYT2RqPwbtBjCHWoNkoA/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Basically i want to do counta() per row but using arrayformula(). The basic formula i use  in A2 :

```
=counta(TRANSPOSE(B2:2))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, but try a [query smush](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/85111204?msgid=85209465) to get started:

`=arrayformula( len( substitute( transpose( query( transpose( left(B2:Z, 1) ), "", 9^9 ) ), " ", "" ) ) )`

There are more than 50,000 blank rows in your sample spreadsheet. You may want to delete them before you apply the formula.

Comment: what does that 9^9 actually do in the query() ?

Comment: See [query smush](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/85111204?msgid=85209465).